# Get string by integer

Tags: sql, sql-server, sql-server-2008

I have a column in db stores Entityid and other one stores Entityname , i need a stored procedure that get name when user insert id (by column name), i have one am working on, how can i improve it.plz explain..

```
ALTER   procedure [dbo].[Emp_CompanyHirarchy]
  @FK_CompanyId varchar(50),
  @FK_EntityId varchar(50)
AS
  SELECT * FROM dbo.RetrieveEntityParent
    WHERE (EntityId =@FK_EntityId)
```

when i excute this, error keeps raise:Msg 216, Level 16, State 1, Procedure Emp_CompanyHirarchy, Line 5
Parameters were not supplied for the function 'dbo.RetrieveEntityParent'.

the function dbo.RetrieveEntityParent:

```
ALTER FUNCTION [dbo].[RetrieveEntityParent] (@FK_EntityId int)
 RETURNS TABLE
 AS RETURN

  with p as
 (SELECT     EntityId, FK_ParentId , EntityName ,EntityArabicName 
  FROM         OrgEntity
 WHERE OrgEntity.EntityId=@FK_EntityId 

  UNION ALL      
  SELECT       PA.EntityId, PA.FK_ParentId, PA.EntityName,PA.EntityArabicName 
  FROM         OrgEntity as PA 
  inner join p
  ON p.FK_ParentId = PA.EntityId)


  select * from p
```

Comment: @ArturUdod i`ve edited my code... plz respond

Comment: The error message complains about a `Employee.FK_EntityId`. Why do *you* think that name is supposed to be valid?

Comment: In the stored procedure you have parameters `@FK_CompanyId` and `FK_EntityId`, but you never use them. Plus: aren't they supposed to be integers?

Comment: @Hans Kesting Yes it was missed because am doing some editing... sorry, i want to pass entityid and get entity name as a result?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is an example for your need in this [link](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!3/c3e2e/8) , but there is a simpler way using the parameter directly in this [link](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!3/c3e2e/12) .

```
DECLARE @FK_EntityId INT

SET @FK_EntityId = 1

SELECT EntityId, FK_ParentId , EntityName ,EntityArabicName 
FROM OrgEntity
WHERE OrgEntity.EntityId = @FK_EntityId 

UNION ALL

SELECT EntityId, FK_ParentId , EntityName ,EntityArabicName 
FROM OrgEntity
WHERE FK_ParentId = @FK_EntityId
```

Comment: please explain your answer.

Comment: You are trying to get the an EntityId and his sons, you can create a function with the query attached, you can watch the query in SQLFiddle that is on the answer.

Answer (score 1):

I can't find `Employee` referred by `Employee.FK_EntityId` in your `RetrieveEntityParent`.
Do you mean `OrgEntity.FK_EntityId`

after your Edit, to get Emp_CompanyHirarchy work you would have to transfer @FK_EntityId as parameter

```
ALTER   procedure [dbo].[Emp_CompanyHirarchy]
  @FK_CompanyId varchar(50),
  @FK_EntityId varchar(50)
AS
  SELECT * FROM dbo.RetrieveEntityParent(@FK_EntityId)
   -- WHERE mybe some other condition
```

BTW: there is some parametertype missmatch with varchar and integer

Comment: Yes it was missed because am doing some editing... sorry, i want to pass entityid and get entity name as a result?